# d3 transitions stop working after timer ends

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I have an animation controlled by `d3.timer()`. After 5 seconds, I have the function return `True` to end the timer and start subsequent functions.

However, when the timer ends, I am unable to use any d3 transitions -- for example, I can't make the SVG fade to black, but I can still brute remove it. Similarly, I can change text, but I can't change the styling.

Why does this happen? Is there a way to fix it?

Here's a jsFiddle of what I'm working with (the problematic transitions are commented at the very bottom): http://jsfiddle.net/Amyunimus/Z59ey/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing this behaviour because

```
endStarted = True;
```

throws an exception -- `True` isn't defined. If you use `'True'` instead, it works. Note that transitions are asynchronous. This means that your code removes the SVG before the transition to black has completed. To fix this, use

```
svg.transition().delay(1000).remove();
```